# List of card with ads on float right using flex or grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

I want to implement this html structure. I tried using flex but doesn't work as last ads column is not the same height and can take up to 2 - 4 rows. and i want to make it responsive too so on resize cards will go on next row if they did not find enough space.

```
.ads {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-column: 6 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 22px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.card {
    margin:0;
}
```

[image: html5 list of cards with ads on float right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news is - we can add ads in a parent container, which is 3 rows height. Here you go

```css
.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr); /* determines 7 columns with same width */
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto); /* determines the height of the row */
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.main-grid>div {
  background: #eee;
}

.main-grid>div.ads-grid {
  background: none;
  grid-area: 1 / 6 / 4 / 8; /* row-start / column-start / row-end / column end */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.main-grid>div.ads-grid>div {
  background: #000;
}

/* example for screens less than 460 */
@media (max-width: 460px) {
  .main-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
  
  .main-grid>div.ads-grid {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 4 / 5;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="main-grid">
  <div class="ads-grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to correct `.main-grid {grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr)}` and `.main-grid>div.ads-grid {grid-area: 1 / 6 / 4 / 8;}` with `@media` width changing for small screens. More about `grid-area` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area

And not a single `flex` was given that day.